# How to invoke TeeChart Wizard in Rad Studio

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, rad-studio

How can i invoke the [TeeChart Wizard](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/TeeChart)?  I'm building an FMX app in C++ Builder (C++Builder 10.3 Version 26.0.33219.4899).  All i see in the Palette is `TChart` and `TChart3D`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [feature matrix](https://www.steema.com/feature_matrix/vcl) the wizard is only available for VCL.

Nevertheless, the IDE allows starting the wizard via main menu: File - New - Other - C++ Builder projects - Windows - TeeChart Wizard. Note that the charts it creates is primarily not fully compatible with FMX.

Comment: Thanks Kerem.  I followed your steps but i don't see "TeeChart Wizard" in my list.  I have: MDI Application, SDI Application, Type Library...Static Library".  What version of Rad Studio are you using?  I'm using 10.3 update 1.

Comment: You're welcome. You have to create an FMX app first. I'm using the same version. Also I testet it again but the IDE crashed. I would recommend using the chart editor.